# How to download files using Google Drive API REST?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, google-api, google-drive-api

I am having difficulties in downloading files from Google Drive using the v3 REST API. I am making the request via axios and getting the array buffer as a response, however, the buffer when saved to a file is corrupted.

These are the response headers that i am getting on making the request:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 date: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 21:36:21 GMT
content-encoding: gzip
expires: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 21:36:21 GMT
server: GSE
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
vary: Origin, X-Origin
cache-control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Content-Type: application/pdf
{file content}
```

I am guessing the gzip compression and utf-8 encoding is what is messing up with the file. I also downloaded the same file via the browser and compared their raw contents and surely the content differs in both the files.

This is how I am making the request currently for which I am getting the above headers and file contents as a response.

```
const {data} = await axios.get(`${exportLink}&${qs.stringify({access_token: access_token})}`, {responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        timeout: 30000,})
```

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/download.js

Comment: Please edit your question and include your full code so it can be tested not just the headers you are sending.

Comment: I have edited the question to include my axios request

Answer (score 0):

As [@Suhakar RS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12167785/sudhakar-rs) said, you can look at [this example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/download.js) to learn how to do it.

This is the relevant part:

```js
drive.files
  .get({fileId, alt: 'media'}, {responseType: 'stream'})
  .then(res => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const filePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), uuid.v4());
      console.log(`writing to ${filePath}`);
      const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
      let progress = 0;

      res.data
        .on('end', () => {
          console.log('Done downloading file.');
          resolve(filePath);
        })
        .on('error', err => {
          console.error('Error downloading file.');
          reject(err);
        })
        .on('data', d => {
          progress += d.length;
          if (process.stdout.isTTY) {
            process.stdout.clearLine();
            process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
            process.stdout.write(`Downloaded ${progress} bytes`);
          }
        })
        .pipe(dest);
    });
  });
```

Notice how the file is requested as a stream and is written in the same format.

Comment: Actually I am using a GET request to download the files instead of the googleapi package, but I have been using axios with responseType: 'arraybuffer'. Do you think changing it to a stream would help?

Comment: Probably. That way you can write directly to your file.

Comment: I tried changing the responseType to 'stream' but to no avail. I am still getting corrupted data :( Do you think content-encoding: gzip and charset : UTF-8 in the response headers has something to do with it?

Comment: Hello! Try using the responseType = 'blob'. Here is some [reference](https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743).

Comment: I tried using the 'blob' but still getting a corrupted file. I will try exploring the google api package source code.

Comment: I found something interesting. When i made the same GET request using Postman, it was able tot fetch the file and the file was not corrupted.